# Git hook to get prior branch name

Tags: git, bash, git-branch, githooks

I'm working on `.git/hooks/post-checkout` and having trouble either sourcing/exporting the branch name, or getting the prior branch name.  I want to restart the server when **switching to or from `s3` branch**.

I couldn't figure out how to source the env var in bash, so I tried using git to get the prior branch, but the closest I got was `git checkout -`/`git checkout @{-1}`, tho I'm not sure simply how to retrieve the prior branch name without the call to checkout.

Should I be using Git env vars instead of shell?

#### Current file just restarts the server on each checkout

```
#!/bin/bash

touch tmp/restart.txt
echo " *** restarting puma-dev"

current_branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
if [ "$current_branch" = "s3" ]
then
  echo " *** please don't upload any files"
  echo
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this line to grab the previous branch name:

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{-1}`

and to get the current branch name:

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Answer (score 2):

Git passes the previous and current ref names to the `post-checkout` hook, so you should be able to do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

oldref="$1"
newref="$2"
branch_update="$3"

[ "$branch_update" = '1' ] || exit  # exit if branch didn't change

[ "$oldref" = 'refs/heads/s3' ] && oldref_was_s3=1
[ "$newref" = 'refs/heads/s3' ] && newref_is_s3=1

if [ -z "$oldref_was_s3" -a -n "$newref_is_s3" ]; then
    echo " *** please don't upload any files"
fi
```

Totally untested, but it should be close.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks in part to Chris, whose method I couldn't interpret or get working, but found the information helpful, and thanks to Keif Kraken, whose method I did get working.

**Restart server when changing to or from a specific branch (s3)**

`.git/hooks/post-checkout` script

```
#!/bin/bash
oldref=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{-1})
newref=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref head)

if [[ ( "$oldref" = "s3" || "$newref" = "s3" ) && "$oldref" != "$newref" ]]
then
  touch tmp/restart.txt
  echo " *** restarting puma-dev"
  echo " *** please don't upload any files"
fi
```

Comment: FYI, I had a silly syntax error in the script.  I tried to use `&&` when I should have been using `-a` for logical AND.  I think my script should now work, and it avoids having to run `git` unnecessarily.